# How to append query string variable to existing URL with history.pushState?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, query-string, pushstate

I currently have a URL which displays all of my projects:
`http://localhost:8090/projects.php`
When I click on one I am able to append a variable to the end of the URL with this simple code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$(".projects-container").on("click", ".procject-listing", function(){
  history.pushState({}, '', '?info='+$(this).attr("id"));
    $(".project-info").show(); 
          });
        });
```

The URL becomes:
`http://localhost:8090/projects.php/?info=23`
Works perfectly. The problem is, when I click inside the "info" div to open another picture, I want the click function to append the picture ID to the end of the URL:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$(".photo-block").on("click", ".photo", function(){
  history.pushState({}, '', '?photo='+$(this).attr("id"));
    $(".photo-viewer").show(); 
          });
        });
```

I was hoping to get a url that looks like:
`http://localhost:8090/projects.php/?info=23?photo=1`
Instead I got:
`http://localhost:8090/projects.php/?photo=1`
Is there any way to append to the URL instead of overwriting the 'already-there' query string variable?
I've been looking at other questions, but they dont seem to be addressing my issue. 
 Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go boss, parse the current URL query string, make a variable, then add it into the equation. It is dynamic as you wanted for its contents are based upon the click.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(".photo-block").on("click", ".photo", function(){
    function query_string(variable){
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
          for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
            var pair = vars[i].split("=");
              if(pair[0] == variable){
                  return pair[1];
                  }}return(false);} 
     history.pushState({}, '','?info=' + info +'?photo='+$(this).attr("id"));
     $(".photo-viewer").show(); 
          });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want multiple querystring variables, you need to join them with a `&`. Thus -> `projects.php?firstVar=1&secondVar=2`.

Alternatively you can also use a hash `#` which wouldn't require you to pushstate, but rather just wrap your pictures in a normal anchor like `projects.php/?info=23#photo1`. The url will change when the user clicks the img

Comment: when replacing the '?photo' with '&photo', i still get the same result. It actually roves the projects part and becomes `http://localhost:8090/&photo=1`

Comment: yes, you obviously need to set it to what you want it to be. It doesn't automatically know which variables you want to keep or not. Change your code `history.pushState({}, '', '?info=3&photo='+$(this).attr("id"));`

Comment: but what if the the '**3**' in the `info=3` varies depending upon the click. If i hard code it, then it will change to a project number that doesnt relate to the photos.

Comment: in your question you say you have that infoId and also the photoId. If not, I would recommend you to use the # hash approach I mentioned in my answer

Comment: i do, but i have 30 projects with 4 photos each, i want it to be dynamic, so the first variable in the query string depends on the click, then the second variable depends on the click, which gets appended to the URL. Then when I copy/paste the url and share it, someone will go to my project, with the info opened, and the picture in view.